# Append To next row excel VBA

Tags: vbscript

This program is working fine I just want to append my tag to next row without any limit.

```
Sub ExportExcel(ByVal Atai)

  Dim a
  Set a = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  a.Visible = True
  a.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Muhammad Awais\Desktop\start and stop data logging\POWER METER 1.xls"

  **
  **a.Sheets("raw data").Cells(3, 4).Value = SmartTags("l1-l2")
  a.Sheets("raw data").Cells(4, 4).Value = SmartTags("l2-l3")
  ****

  a.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Muhammad Awais\Desktop\start and stop data logging\"&Day(Date)& ("_") &Month(Date)& ("_") &Year(Date)& ("_") &Hour(Time)&Minute(Time)&".xls"
 
  a.Workbooks.Close

  a.Quit

  Set a = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: The issue is not very clear. Looks like you are using POWER METER 1.xls as a template, change couple of values by calling SmartTags UDF and saving it as new excel file. Is there an issue in setting the values? If yes, what exactly is SmartTags function doing?

Comment: i will not use save as function. This file will take value each after an hour. So in next file data should append to next row. If i use same this code it will overwrite the existing cell.

Comment: a.Sheets("raw data").Cells(3, 4).Value = SmartTags("l1-l2")   reference to this line there is fixed cell that is 3,4. In this line i want to use append row function in order to put value in next cell i.e. cell(4,4)

Comment: So you want to have just one excel file and append the log information into it? That is easy ... simply find the last used row and then set the values lastrow+1 and lastrow+2

Comment: Dear Mr. Pankaj do you have any sample code can you provide me it will be great help for me. thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=a.Sheets("raw data").Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
```